# How to adjust tikzpicture in the table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics

I insert tikzpicture in a table, but the picture is always not in the center of the cell, especially when in a multirow. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} 
\hline 
Graph & Situation & EV.diff. & Real.diff. & Best response& \# of obs. \\
\hline 
 \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep= 0pt,  minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[player] (2)   at +(0: 1)  {$2$};
\node[player] (3)   at +(0: 2)  {$3$};
\draw (1) to (2)  [line];
\draw (2) to (3)  [line];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
&   1 (3) $\rightarrow$  2  & 4 & 3.7  & 0.854  & 151 \bigstrut\\
&   2 $\rightarrow$ 1 (3)  & -12   & -12    & 0.948 & 77 \bigstrut\\ 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[player] (2)   at (0.7, 1.08)  {$2$};
\node[player] (3)   at (1.4, 0)  {$3$};
\draw (1) to (2)  [line];
\draw (2) to (3)  [line];
\draw (1) to (3)  [line];
\end{tikzpicture} 

\cline{2-6}
& 2  (3)    $\rightarrow$  1  &  4     & 2.67    & 0.24 & 25  \bigstrut\\  

\multirow{5}[5]{*}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[player] (2)   at (-0.7, -1.08)  {$2$};
\node[player] (3)   at (0.7, -1.08)  {$3$};
\node[player] (4)   at (1.4, 0)  {$4$};
\draw (1) to (2)  [line];
\draw (1) to (3)  [line];
\draw (1) to (4)  [line];
\draw (3) to (4)  [line];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\cline{2-6}
& 2 $\rightarrow$ 1  &  -1.33    & 0.8  & 0.39 & 41 \bigstrut\\
& 3  (4)  $\rightarrow$ 1  & 4      & 4.17 & 0.889  & 27 \bigstrut\\
& 3  (4)  $\rightarrow$ 4  (3)  & -4.7   & -6.33  & 0.676  & 37 \bigstrut\\
& 1 $\rightarrow$  3   (4)  & 4    &  4.25 & 0.5 & 32 \bigstrut\\
& 1 $\rightarrow$ 2 & -12   & -12   & 1     & 13 \bigstrut\\          

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The table looks like this:
[image]

I want to place the picture and text in the in the center of each cell of the table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snipped compilable! Add `documentclass{...}`, all necessary packages needed for compilation and than enclose your code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have extra spaces and blank lines in your tabular.  Any line (outside a tikzpicture) which ends with { or } will add an extra space.  use {% and }% instead.  The tikz option [baseline=(bounding box.center)] or using \raisebox{-0.5\height}{...} would help with vertical alignment.

Answer (score 4):

Showed picture you not obtain by showed code snippet ... it has to many errors.

**Edit:**
By help of Bernard answer I succeed to solve remedy in given MWE and now I'm  able to provide complete solution. In it for centering of image I use TikZ picture option `[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]`. In ordinary cells work (to my opinion) very fine, but in `\multirow{...}` cells, now defined with `\multirowcell{...}` from package `makecell` is necessary to consider increased cells height (which at lowest picture accumulate in height of one line).

Beside this I also suggest to use `S` column type for aligning numbers in last four columns of table. Also some optimization is done: all `\tizstyle{...}` (which is obsolete) I define common `\tikzset{...}` used in all three pictures. The obtained picture is:

[image]

The code of above picture is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\tikzset{%
player/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, 
                 inner sep= 0pt,  minimum size=6mm},
  line/.style = {draw=blue, -stealth', semithick, shorten >=1pt}    
                            }% end of tikzset
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc *{4}{S[table-format=-2.2]}}
    \toprule
Graph & Situation & {EV.diff.} & {Real.diff.} & {Best response} & {\# of obs.} \\
  \midrule
 \multirowcell{2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[player] (2) at (0:1)  {$2$};
\node[player] (3) at (0:2)  {$3$};
\draw[line] (1) edge (2)
            (2)  to  (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
                       }
    &   1 (3) $\rightarrow$ 2   & 4     & 3.7  & 0.854  & 151       \\
    &   2 $\rightarrow$ 1 (3)   & -12   & -12  & 0.948  & 77        \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0)      {$1$};
\node[player] (2) at (0.7,1.08) {$2$};
\node[player] (3) at (1.4,0)    {$3$};
\draw[line] (1) edge (2)  
            (2) edge (3) 
            (1)  to  (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
    & 2 (3) $\rightarrow$ 1     &  4    & 2.67 & 0.24   & 25        \\
  \cmidrule{2-6}
 \multirowcell{6}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node[player] (1) at (0,0)        {$1$};
\node[player] (2) at (-0.7,-1.08) {$2$};
\node[player] (3) at (0.7, -1.08) {$3$};
\node[player] (4) at (1.4, 0)     {$4$};
\draw[line] (1) edge (2) 
            (1) edge (3)
            (1) edge (4)
            (3)  to  (4);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
    & 2 $\rightarrow$ 1         & -1.33 & 0.8   & 0.39  & 41        \\
    & 3 (4) $\rightarrow$ 1     & 4     & 4.17  & 0.889 & 27        \\
    & 3 (4) $\rightarrow$ 4 (3) & -4.7  & -6.33 & 0.676 & 37        \\
    & 1 $\rightarrow$ 3 (4)     & 4     & 4.25  & 0.5   & 32        \\
    & 1 $\rightarrow$ 2         & -12   & -12   & 1     & 13        \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `makecell`, `booktabs` (to have some vertical padding around rules) and `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, bigstrut, booktabs, float}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
  \toprule
  Graph & Situation & EV.diff. & Real.diff. & Best response & \# of obs. \\
  \midrule
  \multirowcell{2}[-2\bigstrutjot]{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep= 0pt, minimum size=6mm]
  \tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
  \node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
  \node[player] (2) at +(0: 1) {$2$};
  \node[player] (3) at +(0: 2) {$3$};
  \draw (1) to (2) [line];
  \draw (2) to (3) [line];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
        & 1 (3) $\rightarrow$ 2 & 4 & 3.7 & 0.854 & 151 \bigstrut \\
        & 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 (3) & -12 & -12 & 0.948 & 77 \bigstrut \\
  \cmidrule{2-6}
  \raisebox{-0.45\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6mm]
  \tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
  \node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
  \node[player] (2) at (0.7, 1.08) {$2$};
  \node[player] (3) at (1.4, 0) {$3$};
  \draw (1) to (2) [line];
  \draw (2) to (3) [line];
  \draw (1) to (3) [line];
  \end{tikzpicture}}
        & 2 (3) $\rightarrow$ 1 & 4 & 2.67 & 0.24 & 25 \bigstrut \\
  \cmidrule{2-6}
  \multirowcell{5}[-5\bigstrutjot]{%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{player}= [circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6mm]
  \tikzstyle{line}=[-,draw=blue,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]
  \node[player] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
  \node[player] (2) at (-0.7, -1.08) {$2$};
  \node[player] (3) at (0.7, -1.08) {$3$};
  \node[player] (4) at (1.4, 0) {$4$};
  \draw (1) to (2) [line];
  \draw (1) to (3) [line];
  \draw (1) to (4) [line];
  \draw (3) to (4) [line];
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  }
        & 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 & -1.33 & 0.8 & 0.39 & 41 \bigstrut \\
        & 3 (4) $\rightarrow$ 1 & 4 & 4.17 & 0.889 & 27 \bigstrut \\
        & 3 (4) $\rightarrow$ 4 (3) & -4.7 & -6.33 & 0.676 & 37 \bigstrut \\
        & 1 $\rightarrow$ 3 (4) & 4 & 4.25 & 0.5 & 32 \bigstrut \\
        & 1 $\rightarrow$ 2 & -12 & -12 & 1 & 13 \bigstrut \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]